# A question about series of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about series of complex numbers:
First, for $z\in \mathbb C, |z|<1$, show that $$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{z^n}{n}$$converges.

- Moreover, if we write $z=re^{i\theta}$, give the exact values of the following:$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{z^n}{n},\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{r^ncos(n\theta)}{n},\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{sin(n\theta)}{n}$$
  Then find the value of $$\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n\frac{3^{-n}}{2n+1}$$
- I hope that you can help me solve the problem!

Comment: Use the series of $-\ln (1-z),\,\arctan z$.

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that results for power series over the reals carry over to power series over the complex numbers.

You can apply the ratio test about absolute convergence:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{z^{n+1}/(n+1)}{z^n/n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n+1}|z|=|z|
$$
so the series converges for $|z|<1$. It's a bit more complicated to study the convergence over the circle $|z|=1$.

If you differentiate the given series term by term, you get
$$
\sum_{n\ge0}z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}
$$
which means that
$$
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{z^n}{n}=-\log(1-z)+c
$$
where $\log$ denotes the principal branch. Note that there is no problem, because the region $|z|<1$ doesn't contain points of the negative real axis. If we evaluate at $z=0$, we find $c=0$.

Now note that, for $z=re^{i\theta}$,
$$
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{z^n}{n}=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{r^n(\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta))}{n}
$$
so
$$
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{r^n\cos(n\theta)}{n}=\operatorname{Re}(-\log(1-re^{i\theta}))
\qquad
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{r^n\sin(n\theta)}{n}=\operatorname{Im}(-\log(1-re^{i\theta}))
$$
For the last problem, consider
$$
-\log(1+z)=\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-z)^n}{n}=\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\frac{z^n}{n}
$$
What happens if you sum or subtract the two series?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the ratio test.  $\frac{|z|^{n+1}/(n+1)}{|z|^n/n}=|z|\frac{n}{n+1}\lt|z|\lt 1$ for all $n$, so series converges for $|z|\lt 1$.

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n}$, then $f'(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty z^{n-1}=\frac{1}{1-z}$. Therefore $f(z)=-ln(1-z)$.

For the cos sum, use the representations $cos(n\theta)=\frac{e^{in\theta}+e^{-in\theta}}{2}$and use the result for $f(z)$ above to get $-\frac{ln(1-re^{i\theta})+ln(1-re^{-i\theta})}{2}=-\frac{
ln(1+r^2-2rcos(\theta))}{2}$

See comment about sin sum.

Comment: So what about the following ones... They're really confusing!

Comment: I can't see how your last question relates to the previous.

Comment: The sin sum as stated is not convergent, since $|z|=1$ without $r^n$ multiplier for $r\lt 1$.